# how to make summarized sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure for summary for all kind of numeric data present in my database:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserDashBoardSummarry] 
    @Date as nvarchar(25),
    @UserId as bigint = 0
AS
BEGIN

declare @Data as Table (
ColdCall bigint null ,
WrongNo bigint null ,
NewInq bigint null ,
A bigint null ,
B bigint null ,
C bigint null ,
D bigint null ,
E bigint null ,
F bigint null ,
Followup bigint null ,
ID bigint null,
NEW bigint null,
Meeting_Reminder bigint null,
KYC bigint null,
Wealth_Protection bigint null,
DONE bigint null,
Review_meet bigint null,
Sampoorna_Surksha bigint null,
QUOTATION bigint null,
Sam_Raksh_review_report bigint null,
Portfolio_Review_for_existing_client bigint null,
Seminar bigint null,
Seminar_Registration bigint null,
Registration_confirmation bigint null,
For_safal_investor bigint null,
JUST_2_HOUR_TO_GO bigint null
)

insert into @Data(ColdCall,WrongNo,NewInq,A,B,C,D,E,F,Followup,ID)
select  
0,0,0,
sum((CASE WHEN [inq_category] = 16 then 1 else 0 end)) as A, 
sum((CASE WHEN [inq_category] = 17 then 1 else 0 end)) as B, 
sum((CASE WHEN [inq_category] = 18 then 1 else 0 end)) as C, 
sum((CASE WHEN [inq_category] = 19 then 1 else 0 end)) as D,  
sum((CASE WHEN [inq_category] = 20 then 1 else 0 end)) as E,   
sum((CASE WHEN [inq_category] = 21 then 1 else 0 end)) as F,      
count(*)  as cnt,[followup_by] as ID From [dbo].[followup]  where 1=1 
and dbo.Formated_Date(followup_date) = dbo.Formated_Date(@Date)  
and ( @UserId = 0 OR [followup_by] = @UserId)
group by followup_by  

insert into @Data(ColdCall,WrongNo,NewInq,A,B,C,D,E,F,Followup,ID)
select  
0,0,  
count(*) as inq,  
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  
[Inq_By] as ID  
 from [dbo].[Inq_Master]  
where dbo.Formated_Date(Date_Time) = dbo.Formated_Date(@Date)  
and ( @UserId = 0 OR [Inq_By] = @UserId)
group by [Inq_By] 

insert into @Data(ColdCall,WrongNo,NewInq,A,B,C,D,E,F,Followup,ID)
select   
sum((CASE WHEN status = 1 then 1 else 0 end)) as ColdCall,  
sum((CASE WHEN status = 3 then 1 else 0 end)) as WrongNo, 
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  
UserId as ID   
 from [dbo].[ColdCall]  
where dbo.Formated_Date(DateTime) = dbo.Formated_Date(@Date) 
and ( @UserId = 0 OR UserId = @UserId)
group by UserId  


select 
(select [username] From [dbo].[web_user_master] where [pk_id] = ID) as Name, 
sum(ColdCall) + sum(WrongNo) + sum(Followup) as Total,
sum(ColdCall) as ColdCall, 
sum(WrongNo) as WrongNo, 
sum(NewInq) as NewInq,   
sum(Followup) - sum(NewInq) as Old_F,
'|' as '|',
sum(Followup) as Tot_F,
sum(A) as A, 
sum(B) as B, 
sum(C) as C, 
sum(D) as D, 
sum(E) as E, 
sum(F) as F  
from @Data
group by ID

insert into @Data(NEW,Meeting_Reminder,KYC,Wealth_Protection,DONE,Review_meet,Sampoorna_Surksha,QUOTATION,Sam_Raksh_review_report,Portfolio_Review_for_existing_client,Seminar,Seminar_Registration,Registration_confirmation,For_safal_investor,JUST_2_HOUR_TO_GO)

select  
(select [username] From [dbo].[web_user_master] where [pk_id] = [followup_by]) as Name,
sum((CASE WHEN party_category =1 then 1 else 0 end)) as NEW,
sum((CASE WHEN party_category =2 then 1 else 0 end)) as Meeting_Reminder,
sum((CASE WHEN party_category =3 then 1 else 0 end)) as KYC,
sum((CASE WHEN party_category =4 then 1 else 0 end)) as Wealth_Protection,
sum((CASE WHEN party_category =29 then 1 else 0 end)) as DONE,
sum((CASE WHEN party_category =33 then 1 else 0 end)) as Review_meet,
sum((CASE WHEN party_category =111 then 1 else 0 end)) as Sampoorna_Surksha,
sum((CASE WHEN party_category =112 then 1 else 0 end)) as QUOTATION,
sum((CASE WHEN party_category =113 then 1 else 0 end)) as Sam_Raksh_review_report,
sum((CASE WHEN party_category =114 then 1 else 0 end)) as Portfolio_Review_for_existing_client,
sum((CASE WHEN party_category =115 then 1 else 0 end)) as Seminar,
sum((CASE WHEN party_category =10147 then 1 else 0 end)) as Seminar_Registration,
sum((CASE WHEN party_category =10148 then 1 else 0 end)) as Registration_confirmation,
sum((CASE WHEN party_category =10149 then 1 else 0 end)) as For_safal_investor,
sum((CASE WHEN party_category =10150 then 1 else 0 end)) as JUST_2_HOUR_TO_GO,

count(*) as cnt , [followup_by] as ID
From [dbo].[followup_party]  where 1=1  
and dbo.Formated_Date(followup_date) = dbo.Formated_Date(@Date)
and ( @UserId = 0 OR [followup_by] = @UserId)
group by [followup_by]

END
```

When I execute query then it gives the following errors:

> Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetUserDashBoardSummarry, Line 68
> The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list.
> Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetUserDashBoardSummarry, Line 98
> The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list.

How can i resolve this? What's going wrong here?

Comment: The error *is* telling you the problem here; what about the error don't you understand here and we can elaborate.

Comment: `dbo.Formated_Date(followup_date) = dbo.Formated_Date(@Date)` has a code smell to it. Why is `followup_date` and `@Date` not a date? [`(n)varchar` is *not* a "one type fits all" data type](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-varchar-is-not-a-one-size-fits-all-data-type/). Doing such comparisons is going to be really poor for performance; especially if you're not on SQL Server 2019+ (so it can't be inlined) or it's written as a multi-line scalar function (and you are on SQL Server 2019+).